# Scroll element horizontally, with unspecified width

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

I'm trying to scroll an element horizontally, with its parent's overflow set to hidden.

Here's what I've got so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="scroll">This element's text scrolls horizontally.</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 36px;
}
.scroll {
    width: 1500px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    var $parent = $('.parent'),
        $scroll = $('.scroll'),
        width = $scroll.width(),
        scroll = function (){
            $scroll.animate({
                'margin-left': -width
            }, 12000, function () {
                $scroll.css('margin-left', $parent.width());
                scroll();
            });
        };

    scroll();
});​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hTnNk/

---

The above works flawlessly, but has the inner element (`.scroll`) with a fixed width.

Is there any way to accomplish this without setting the inner element's width explicitly?

Comment: Somewhere you will need a 'fixed' width (even if its a percentage of the viewport). Otherwise the content will just expand infinitely (never triggering the need for a scroll bar.)

Comment: @KevinBoucher - Since the text comes from a CMS, there's no way to determine its width ahead of time.

Comment: Ahh. I think I misunderstood the question. Looks like @GionaF has what you need.

Comment: @KevinBoucher - That doesn't really accomplish the above effect. See my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add:

```
.scroll {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

and replace `width = $scroll.width()` with:

```
width = $scroll.get(0).scrollWidth
```

It'll work fine without an explicit width set. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/v6e5S/)

Comment: The element doesn't scroll all the way to left though, because its width ends at the right edge of the parent element.

Comment: Oh, i missed that @MegaHit. Check my edit, it's working now ;)

Comment: That's just an arbitrary width that happens to work in your demo. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/pvfcM/2/

Comment: Wasn't thinking about `scrollWidth`. Check my edit again @MegaHit and: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/v6e5S/)

Comment: This makes the element scroll way past the left edge of its parent, which makes the parent be empty for a longer period of time: http://jsfiddle.net/v6e5S/3/

Comment: wops, again. just remove  `+ $parent.width()` http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/v6e5S/4/

Comment: ...now i know how to do it too @MegaHit ;-) ciao!